# I need plugins for Edgewall Trac

Tags: plugins, trac, bug-tracking

I need the following plugins for Trac (if exist):

- Diagrams: Gantt and other;
- Export to MS Excel;
- Dashboards: control panels, monitors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pointers in order of your request with some remarks, citations from the plugin description or own experience if applicable:

- for Gantt diagrams there are actually multiple choices (in total absence of own experience roughly in order of likelihood of usability):

  - [TracJsGanttPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracJsGanttPlugin) by jsgantt, computed % completion, actively maintained
  - [GanttCalendarPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GanttCalendarPlugin) - manually set % completion, month view for tickets, maintained
  - [FlashGanttPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/FlashGanttPlugin) based on FusionCharts Free - just for milestones, not for tickets, seems unmaintained
  - [SchedulingToolsPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SchedulingToolsPlugin), early beta, definitely unmaintained
  - [GanttChartPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GanttChartPlugin) no dynamic, just YAML text block to Gantt markup processor, seems unmaintained
- [ExcelDownloadPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ExcelDownloadPlugin) - using this myself: works great, there's even i18n support on the way
- [WhiteboardPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WhiteboardPlugin) - not totally convinced here

More generally I recommend [TracStatsPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracStatsPlugin) to you for making a nice bundled view with navigation to sub-pages on topics (repo, ticket, wiki). It looks tidy and useful, and it has a responsive maintainer.

Comment: I've been advised to add a hint on http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracGvizPlugin for someone, who likes using Google's visualization gadgets.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great site called [Trac Hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/).  A quick search here will show you many different plugins for handling Visualizations.  [Here is a quick list](http://trac-hacks.org/tags/%27chart%27) of plugins that do visualizations.

As for an export to Excel, what are you trying to export? For Tickets and reports, at the bottom of each page, there is an option to export to a comma or tab delimited Text file.  This can be opened in Excel.  If that is not enough, here are three plugins that will export to Excel

- [ExcelDownloadPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ExcelDownloadPlugin)
- [ExportImportXlsPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ExportImportXlsPlugin)
- [ExcelReportPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ExcelReportPlugin)

I hope this helps.

Josh

Comment: Hm, I put a bit more effort into my plugin selection for you, hence it took a little longer. ;-)